# Not possible to change button text via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, squarespace

Probaby a very simple question for you jQuery wizards, but I don't manage to change the innerHTML of a button via jQuery. I have the following Squarespace page: https://hethuisvandelingerie.squarespace.com/badmode/BM001 .

What I want to do is to change the text in the "Add to cart" button from English to Dutch. The button has the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487777852612_138" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button sqs-suppress-edit-mode sqs-editable-button " data-collection-id="5890a2ff2e69cf43f9dad6c5" data-item-id="589f1443c0302664f13c7656" data-original-label="Add To Cart" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487777852612_146">
        <div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner">Add To Cart</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use the following jQuery script to change the text in the button. I added the first part of code to see if my jQuery (of which I've injected the link to the API elsewhere) works. A "Yeah" alert is given, so this is not the issue. However, the button text does not seem to change :(.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
      } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
      }
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
       $(".sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner").text("Voeg toe aan mandje");
    });
</script>
```

jQuery guru's, help me out please! 
Kr,
BarrieO

Comment: if you put an alert before the line that change the text what did you have ?

Comment: run it on $(document).ready rather than $(window).load

Comment: You should also check to see if its using the version of jQuery, the call can instead be jQuery not $. In the console, type $ and hit enter, if you get an undefined response then type jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(document).ready()` in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner").text("Voeg toe aan mandje");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487777852612_138" style="visibility: visible;">
  <div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button sqs-suppress-edit-mode sqs-editable-button " data-collection-id="5890a2ff2e69cf43f9dad6c5" data-item-id="589f1443c0302664f13c7656" data-original-label="Add To Cart" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487777852612_146">
    <div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner">Add To Cart</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although the code seems perfectly fine now, it still does not work on my website. I changed it in the link in my original message. Don't understand why it is still not working... :(

Comment: multiple versions or no version of jQuery included? @BarrieO

Comment: Hmm, unless Squarespace already inlcudes some jQuery by default, I've only include this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery seems to be loaded as the test alert "Yeah" is displayed?

Comment: jQuery needs to be referenced before using it.

Comment: @jfox Very dumb of me indeed, when looking in the code rendered by Squarespace, I see that the jQuery script is loaded after my code to change the button text. You were right jfox. Thanks a lot! Can I mark this as an answer or give you some credit in some way? I am quite new to Stackoverflow...